# Why Androids default way of handling the events is to recreate the activity?

Tags: android

Androids default way of handling the events is to recreate the activity so i wanted to know why the android has it as default behavior as recreation of the activity can be costly process.

Comment: Handling events such as configuration changes?  Because the system may need to load different resources than it had before such as a layout specifically for portrait or landscape.  You can override the behavior if you know for sure what's going to happen.  Most people don't need to though, hence the reason for the recreation by default.  http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html#RestoreState

Comment: `Androids default way of handling the events is to recreate the activity` . **NO**: Most events, such as a click listener, aren't handled by recreating the Activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the android Dev site:  http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html

"Some device configurations can change during runtime (such as screen orientation, keyboard availability, and language). When such a change occurs, Android restarts the running Activity (onDestroy() is called, followed by onCreate()). The restart behavior is designed to help your application adapt to new configurations by automatically reloading your application with alternative resources that match the new device configuration."

"However, you might encounter a situation in which restarting your application and restoring significant amounts of data can be costly and create a poor user experience. In such a situation, you have two other options:

1. Retain an object during a configuration change

   - Allow your activity to restart when a configuration changes, but
     carry a stateful object to the new instance of your activity.
2. Handle the configuration change yourself

   - Prevent the system from restarting your activity during certain
     configuration changes, but receive a callback when the
     configurations do change, so that you can manually update your
     activity as necessary."

Overall, Handling events such as configuration changes is because the system may needs to load different resources than it had before such as a layout specifically for portrait or landscape. You can override the behavior if you know for sure what's going to happen. Most people don't need to though, hence the reason for the recreation by default. More info on the lifecyce is available at developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/